# Geowebcache alias for custom projections

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, epsg, geowebcache

Is there a way to configure a projection alias in geowebcache?

E.g. if I would like to advertise projection EPSG:25833 and EPSG:32633 to the client, while requesting tiles from the backend using EPSG:25833. That is for (mostly) identical projections where no reprojection is needed.

The idea being of course that identical tiles are only cached (and requested) once, while both projections are advertised.

Answer (score 1):

I thought a little about your requests then I checked the geowebcache.xsd spec and I don't think you can do this without some customization within the code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw that you can easily hardcode aliases in SRS.java. I'm just surprised that I seem to be the first to have that request. :)

Comment: I tried that in the meantime, but no luck. The aliases don't seem to be used but in special cases.

Comment: What would you think - is it possible to just create the folders on disk as a hard or soft link (e.g. EPSG_25833_1 to EPSG_32633_1)? I cannot see that geowebcache would have reason to complain or conflict.